# Tensorflow: What exact formula is applied in `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`?

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to manually recompute the outputs of this function so I created a minimal example:

```
logits = tf.pack(np.array([[[[0,1,2]]]],dtype=np.float32)) # img of shape (1, 1, 1, 3)
labels = tf.pack(np.array([[[1]]],dtype=np.int32)) # gt of shape (1, 1, 1)

softmaxCrossEntropie = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,labels)
softmaxCrossEntropie.eval() # --> output is [1.41]
```

Now according to my own calculation I only get [1.23]
When manually calculating, I'm simply applying softmax

[image]

and cross-entropy:

[image]

where `q(x) = sigma(x_j) or (1-sigma(x_j))` depending whether j is the correct ground truth class or not  and `p(x) = labels` which are then one-hot-encoded

I'm not sure where the difference might originate from. I cannot really imagine that some epsilon causes such a big difference. Does someone know where I can lookup, which exact formula is used by tensorflow?
Is the source code of that exact part available?
I could only find [`nn_ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py), but it only uses another function called `gen_nn_ops._sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` which I couldn't find on github...

Comment: `gen_nn_ops._sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is use cpp code to write in core package, the source file is `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d699a66e940b26e991b29b27f4e3ad2e8e3282d2/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_xent_op.cc`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, usually `p(x)` in cross-entropy equation is true distribution, while `q(x)` is the distribution obtained from softmax. So, if `p(x)` is one-hot (and this is so, otherwise sparse cross-entropy could not be applied), cross entropy is just negative log for probability of true category.

In your example, `softmax(logits)` is a vector with values `[0.09003057,  0.24472847,  0.66524096]`, so the loss is `-log(0.24472847) = 1.4076059` which is exactly what you got as output.

Comment: Ahh. I was assuming the wrong formula (`y log(p) + (1-y) log(1-p)`) which is for binary cross entropy only apparently. Also I mistakenly used log_10 instead of log_e. Thanks a lot for clearing that!

Comment: The name is confusing, but sparse cross-entropy loss can not be applied when the labels are one-hot. It is sparse because it saves you from creating the dense one hot matrix.

Comment: why you call `e^(x_i)` as logits?